# Последовательное отображение элементов массива по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

При нажатии на кнопку сначала должен отображаться черный, а потом синий, заменяя друг друга. Но происходит так, что отображается сразу последний. Думаю, что так происходит, потому что при нажатии на кнопку цикл проходит до момента завершения. Не понимаю, как откорректировать код, чтобы исправить эту ошибку

```js
let mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');
let allBlocks = [
        '<div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: red"></div>',
        '<div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: black"></div>',
        '<div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: blue"></div>',
    ];

    let next = document.getElementById('next');
    next.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {
            mainDiv.innerHTML = allBlocks[i];
        }
    });
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center;">
    <div id="main">
    <div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: red"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="next">-></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');
let allBlocks = [
    '<div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: red"></div>',
    '<div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: green"></div>',
    '<div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: blue"></div>',
];
const next = document.getElementById('next');
next.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const block = allBlocks.shift();
    mainDiv.innerHTML = block;
    allBlocks.push(block);
});
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center;">
    <div id="main">
    <div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: black"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="next">-></button>
    </div>
</div>
```